# Ajax call to method on controller is not working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I'm quite new to MVC and I'm trying to call a method int one of my controllers.

```
<script>
function checkCardNumber() {

    var content = $('#card-number').val();
    var url = "AccountController/CheckRegisteredCard";
    alert("content and URL are set");
    $.post(url, { cardNumber: content }, function (data) {            
        alert(data);
    });
    alert("called outside of Post");
}
</script>
```

and here's the C# controller side:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string CheckRegisteredCard(string cardNumber)
    {            
        if (/*some condition*/)
        {
            return "";
        }            
        else
        {                
            return "some string";
        }
    }
```

both alerts("content and URL are set", "called outside of post") are being triggered, but the ajax part is not working at all. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your controller class is called `AccountController`, the url should be `/Account/CheckRegisteredCard`.

Have you checked the network tab of your browser? I bet there's a 404 error.

If this snippet of javascript is in a .cshtml file, I would recommend using [`@Url.Action()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.Action%28System.String,System.String%29) to get the url string.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using Fiddler and having that open when the ajax call is being made.  This will tell you (1) if the call is being made at all or failing immediately, and (2) what kind of response you are receiving from the controller.  Also agree with Jason P about how the url should be calling the controller.